# template template parameters not working

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following classes:

```
    template <class T, size_t dims> class dataType { ... };

    class heapType {...}; // Not templated so far.

    class dataClass {....};
```

These two classes work properly. Now I want to do the following:

```
    template < template <class T, size_t dims> class data_t, class heap_t> algorithmType {...};
```

The objective is to use `algorithmType` with the other classes as policies:

```
    algorithmType <dataType<dataClass,2>, heapType> myAlgorithm;
```

But this throws the following errors:

```
    error: ‘myAlgorithm’ was not declared in this scope
    algorithmType <dataType<dataClass,2>, heapType> myAlgorithm;
    ^

    error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
    algorithmType <dataType<dataClass,2>, heapType> myAlgorithm;
                                        ^
    error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
    algorithmType <dataType<dataClass,2>, heapType> myAlgorithm;
                                                  ^
    error: ‘myAlgorithm’ was not declared in this scope
    algorithmType <dataType<dataClass,2>, heapType> myAlgorithm;
```

I am following the first chapter of the Modern C++ book in which something similar is done.
where is the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a template template parameter, but you're passing a *type* in, not a *template.* Either change the use and pass in a template:

```
 algorithmType <dataType, heapType> myAlgorithm;
```

Or change the declaration to accept a type:

```
template < class data_t, class heap_t> algorithmType {...};
```

Which one depends on your intended usage.

If `algorithmType` just wants a class passed in, change it to have a template type paremeter, and pass in the class `dataType<dataClass,2>` as you're doing now. It doesn't matter that the class was instantiated from a template, it's a *class.*

If, on the other hand, you want `algorithmType` to be able to provide its own template parameters to its input template parameter, keep it as a template template parameter and just pass the template in.

Comment: Changing the declaration as you said (second option) and then doing ` algorithmType <dataClass, heapType> myAlgorithm` throw exactly the same error. I am still trying to fully understand the rest of the answer :)

Comment: If I use your first option, just changing the use of the class, the error is that dataType is missing 2 template parameters.

Comment: @JaviV Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? The errors can be coming from slightly different places, or depend on other pieces of the code. But in principle: `dataType` is a template, `dataType<x, y>` is a type. You have to provide the former to a template template parameter, the latter to a template type parameter (and then **use the parameter accordingly**, of course).

Comment: This is weird. I tried to make a compilable version of the code taking into account your second option and it works properly. But I cannot export it to the other real code (which is much bigger). I will post the problem when I find it, now I know how it is done in theory :)

Comment: I found only one difference. In my real code, `dataClass` inherits from another, simple class. Can this cause the error?

Comment: I found the problem. Actually it was the #ifndef MYALGORITHM_H_ header in the class. The compilation problems were not due to the way I was passing the template. Anyway, your answer is helpful, you saved me from a future compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `algorithmType` expects a template class accepting type and int as the first argument, and you are passing a concrete type.

To put it simpler, this is a correct way to define that variable :

```
algorithmType <dataType, heapType> myAlgorithm;
```

---

From the comment, I see that you do not understand what template class as a template argument means.

Next example compiles, and shows how to use template class as a template argument :

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>

template< template < class, class > class V >
struct A
{
    V< int, std::allocator<int> > container;
};



int main()
{
    A< std::vector > a1;  // container is std::vector<int>
    A< std::list > a2;    // container is std::map<int>
}
```

If you need to pass a concrete type, then change algorithmType to :

```
template class data_t, class heap_t> algorithmType {...};
```

Comment: But if do that, then how does `myAlgorithm` know which type is `T` and the value of `dims`? I need `myAlgorithm` to know those, although it could extract it from `dataType`. In fact, if I declare it this way, I  get the following error error: missing template arguments before ‘,’ token`

Comment: @JaviV But if you only pass the template, there *will be no `T` and `dims`,* as you're not passing an instantiation, just the template. You algorithm will have to supply those. Does this help make the distinction more clear?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but then I do not know how to do it.